# TypeError: can't pickle generator objects: Spark collect() fails due to unserializable generator return type (dict_key)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, generator, pickle, databricks

I have a library function that returns a compound object containing generators, which can't be pickled (trying to pickle generates the error `TypeError: can't pickle dict_keys objects`).

When I try to parallelize via Spark, it fails on the collect step, due to pickle failure (nb. running via DataBricks with default `sc`).

Here is a minimal repro:

```python
test_list = [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, 
             {"a": 7, "b": 3, "c": 5}, 
             {"a": 2, "b": 3, "c": 4}, 
             {"a": 9, "b": 8, "c": 7}]

parallel_test_list = sc.parallelize(test_list)

parallel_results = parallel_test_list.map(lambda x: x.keys())

local_results = parallel_results.collect()
```

The stack trace I receive is long, I think the relevant part is:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 403, in main
        process()
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 398, in process
        serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 418, in dump_stream
        bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)
      File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 597, in dumps
        return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol)
    TypeError: can't pickle dict_keys objects

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:490)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:626)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:609)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a recursive helper function to "consume" all the nested generator objects, and `map` all your rows in your `rdd` with this function.

For example, here's a function that will turn nested generators into `list`s:

```python
from inspect import isgenerator, isgeneratorfunction

def consume_all_generators(row):

    if isinstance(row, str):
        return row
    elif isinstance(row, dict):
        return {k: consume_all_generators(v) for k, v in row.items()}

    output = []
    try:
        for val in row:
            if isgenerator(val) or isgeneratorfunction(val):
                output.append(list(consume_all_generators(val)))
            else:
                output.append(consume_all_generators(val))
        return output
    except TypeError:
        return row
```

Now call `map(consume_all_generators)` before `collect`:

```python
local_results = parallel_results.map(consume_all_generators).collect()
print(local_results)
#[['a', 'c', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'b']]
```